# minizinc python installation

Tags: python, importerror, minizinc

I installed minizinc on python through anaconda prompt as normally with other packages.

```
pip install minizinc
```

The package says it was installed successfully and I can import the module. However, I'm following the basic example https://minizinc-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#a-basic-example
but Once I run the first line

```
from minizinc import Instance, Model, Solver
```

and I'm getting the import error below:

```
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Instance' from 'minizinc' 
(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\minizinc\__init__.py)
```

This is the only package I have problems with. My current python version is 3.7 which according to https://minizinc-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#a-basic-example should support minizinc. If anyone has faced the same issue and fixed the problem I'll appreciate any feedback regarding this problem.

Comment: Are you sure MiniZinc itself (the MiniZinc bundle) is installed on the running machine?

Comment: well, I just did the pip install minizinc on anaconda prompt. Do I still need to install minizinc on my pc? I thought I could use minizinc just by installing the package.

Comment: oh I just did installed minizinc now I can run the example many thanks @Dekker1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MiniZinc bundle (or at least the `minizinc` executable) should be installed in order to use MiniZinc Python. It is noted as one of the required dependencies in the installation documentation.

When the `minizinc` executable is not found, MiniZinc Python will output the following warning to indicate that the executable could not be located:

```
MiniZinc was not found on the system: no default driver could be initialised
```