# why does minizinc python show TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Instance with abstract methods

Tags: python, minizinc

0

Though i've Minizinc installed in my PC! still getting this error:
--> 12 instance = Instance(gecode, nqueens)
ImportError: cannot import name 'Instance' from 'minizinc'  So,
i modified the code :
from minizinc.instance import Instance
But i've got:
---> 12 instance = Instance(gecode, nqueens)
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Instance with abstract methods init, branch, method, solutions

trying to follow :
[minizinc python installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63016535/minizinc-python-installation/72067985#72067985)
but without a result

Comment: still getting thid error:

Comment: RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

---> 10 result = instance.solve()
    
--> 118             return asyncio.run(coroutine)


---> 33         raise RuntimeError(
     34             "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")
     35 

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Answer (score 0):

I​t sounds like you are using a Jupyter notebook, which has a known problem: since it uses asynchronous Python loop, it cannot call anything that itself also calls an asynchronous Python loop. For MiniZinc Python this is discussed here: https://github.com/MiniZinc/minizinc-python/issues/38 which also gives a few solutions